How do I find optimal learning rate in Sagemaker Catboost training?
In Sagemaker, the out-of-the-box catboost model uses a default learning rate of 0.03. On my local set up (catboost 1.2), the learning rate is calculated automatically based on data characteristics.
Is there a way to set the learning rate automatically in Sagemaker as well, or to calculate the rate beforehand and input it as a parameter?
I understand I can make my own catboost installation via Docker, but I am wondering if this can be solved with the default Sagemaker model.

Hi, do you mean provide the learning rate when starting the training job? You can provide custom hyperparameters to the training job, like shown in the example here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/catboost.html#catboost-sample-notebooks

Hi, I do not mean providing the learning rate myself, but letting catboost calculate based on the dataset. On my local installation, e.g. catboost chooses 0.06 as the ideal learning rate based on my dataset and number of iterations. It's really great for a starting point.

ah makes sense. I doubt there's such a capability with the built-in algorithm today.

I found no way of finding the optimal learning_rate using Sagemaker out-of-the-box catboost model, which is a shame.
There are two alternative ways:

Setting up a Docker container on SageMaker with own catboost image, for example using this tutorial
Running a local job: in case the data fits into RAM and cb.fit() does not error out, optimal learning_rate is one of the first information outputted by the algorithm. It can then be inputted manually into Sagemaker out-of-the-box model.

